# Trying to find this book for years I know the book has a the title? And a (purple?) Flame

Tags: story-identification

One boy goes to a magic school, where he is excited to meet his roommate only to find out that he is (a year older than him?) a green mage, while he is a red or fire mage.  At some point they go to a party. The green mage makes him stand a the head of the table and stares at him, while controlling a sunflower to fight the other sunflower on the table.  He (the main character) uses his magic to make a flame just like the green mage's body and copy his every movement. At one point, the red mage gets drugged and almost raped by another boy; green stops this and takes him back to room and things happen. Both wake up naked in same bed and tell each other they love each other.

Comment: https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/35576261?

Comment: https://embed.wattpad.com/story/226942554-the-green-mage?

Comment: Do you remember the year when you read it? Where do you bought it? This might be helpful. We need more data in order to help you.

Comment: @Feuergeist ... good questions.  But Eveny Zamora, who asked the question, has not been here for more than five years.

Comment: Maybe he is laughing at us.

Comment: I think neither of the suggestions of @Valorum match the description.